# Can you create a file or folder by path in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

In Atom, hitting Cmd+N brings up a window where you can type in basically any path to create any file or folder anywhere in the project. In VSCode, hitting Cmd+N brings up a dialog where you can create a file in the currently focused folder, and I believe you can type a path to create a file in a subfolder (whether it exists or not), but not as flexibly as in Atom.

Is there way to do it Atom-style in VSCode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for sure whether this is what you're looking for, but still there exists [this plugin](https://ritwickdey.github.io/vscode-create-file-folder/) **which can emulate the file/directory creation feature of Atom.**

Since i use vscode-vim it's fairly easy to create new folders and files using command mode. If you're familiar with using terminal, then you can use shell commands to create file/dir.

I have no idea whether one could do what you had mentioned the proper way with vanilla vscode.

Hope this helps you somehow.

Comment: Thanks! That plugin does appear to do what I want, although it doesn't appear to pre-fill with the "Current folder". But using mkdir via terminal is not something I thought of and is of course a great simple solution.